# Accounting Transection in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have to develop a ERP System for a pharmaceuticals Company. 
I use `mysql` AS my database management system and `php` AS scripting language.
Accounting module is one of the main module in ERP system. 
Now I want to know about accounting transaction in mysql. 
In One Click two transaction save on database one is debit another is credit transaction. 
Let Debit transaction ok then when credit transaction going to save in database at the same time transaction failed for power loss or internet connection loss. 
Now How cant I prevent this type of problem. 
I want to entry two transaction at a time. 
If one transaction failed then second transaction no run and first transaction will be rollback.

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) about transactions. Maybe that will help you.

```
START TRANSACTION;
//command 1
//command 2
COMMIT;
```

If command 2 returns error run

```
ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: I depends on your decision. If you will do that in php you can choose to  continue executing commands or run `ROLLBACK;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is Transaction Management in MySQl , which can take care by creating  [Store Procedure and Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html).

Comment: can you give an example? how to manage it my stored procedure

Comment: here you can see example [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

Comment: you can preform both task in single transaction and if any error occur you can rollback whole transaction [link](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/manage_transactions_in_mysql_-_lesson_2/)